# Application layer scaling while depending on a single DB

Tags: architecture, scaling

How can running multiple instances of my backend improve performance if they are all backed with a single Database (served with the same database instance)

Because I think that most of the latency of the request is caused by the database, shouldn't I focus first on database performance/scalability rather running multiple instances of the application and hope for the best?

Comment: "I think that most of the latency of the request is caused by" - don't think, measure. Once you know what's slowing things down, work on that.

Comment: There are also other reasons for scaling beyond performance. Reliability factors in too. Your front is much more likely to have a service denying bug than most long matured database engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that many times servers do cache some of the data they get from DB. Also take note that server can perform some operations before sending data to DB so you may or may not benefit from having multiple instances. In order to figure out how to scale your application with success you need to measure it, identify bottlenecks and address them. Just thinking this or that is often misleading.